# Mongoose throws badvalue on coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
module.exports = function (mongoose) {
    var Location = mongoose.Schema({
        street: String,
        number: String,
        zip: String,
        floor: String,
        rental: String,
        size: Number,
        loc: {
            type: {type: String},
            coordinates: []
        },
        updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    });

    return mongoose.model('Location', Location);
};
```

i am trying to query the data the following way:

```
mongoose.models.Location.find({
    loc: {
        $near: [55.69841959999999,12.5443359],
        $maxDistance: 2000
    }
}, function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
```

However i get an error saying:

```
> error processing query: ns=RentalDB.locationsTree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=2000 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query
```

Can anyone tell me what ive done wrong?

Comment: Exactly what the error says. There's no index on the field. You need to [create a "2dsphere" index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/). You can add an index through the schema definition, or manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your geoData should be in correct format while storing.

Coordinates are numbers not string

Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#legacy-coordinate-pairs

Answer (score 0):

Doumentation about [geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/geoNear/)

> Returns documents in order of proximity to a specified point, from the
>   nearest to farthest. geoNear requires a geospatial index.

You need to create a geospatial index.

Comment: I have attempted to do this in the console by doing:db.RentalDB.createIndex({ "point": "2dsphere" })

However that didnt help

Comment: I guess `point` must be the name of the field that hold the coordinates. In your case much like `locs` or something. Look  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) for detailled example of `creating geospacial index`

Comment: I have also tried: > db.Location.createIndex( { "loc.coordinates": "2d" } )

Comment: The create index should return an error that you can use to know what to change in your command

Comment: Ok so I red the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-geojson). Your field loc is bad typed. You need to use a field that's a `GeoJSON Point` or a `Legacy Coordinate Pairs`.